# Three js VR video angle change gyroscope

Tags: three.js, 360-virtual-reality

Three js has this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webxr_vr_video.html  But the angle doesnt change perspective when you move the phone around unless you enter VR mode.

I am looking for a way to make video behave in mobile browser as demonstrated here: https://bitmovin.com/demos/vr-360  When you move mobile phone around you can see different angles of the video (that is before you even enter VR mode by clicking glasses icon).

Comment: I assume that example is using a custom app. The need for a 'user authorization for entering VR mode' is covered by https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/webxr-permission-info-page and https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr/privacy-security-explainer.html